# Wrap text in pdf reports

Tags: genexus

I have two questions about pdf reports with Genexus, I hope somebody can help me:

1) how can I wrap the text value of a variable in PDF reports?

2) I saw that textblock controls are the only ones that have the wrap property, so, in this case, how can I assign a value dinamically?

Best regards,
Leonardo

Comment: Maybe if you post some code, will be easier to help you.

Comment: It's always good to post the version and generator of Genexus that you are using. Please, edit your post to the information.

Comment: Hi it is evolution 3 up2. .net generator for web.

Answer (score 2):

In reports, to wrap text in variables (typically Varchar or LongVarchar fields) you can use the [GXMLines](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?GXMLines%20Function,) and [GXGetMLi](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?GXGetMLi%20Function,) functions.

Example:

```
&nlin = GXMLines(&LongText,40)
For &i = 1 to &nlin
    &txtLine = GXGetMLi(&LongText, &i, 40)
    Print txtLines // (printblock that prints &txtLine)
EndFor
```

Comment: Yes, I know this is the common way, but not the desirable. I supposed that in Ev3 we will have something better. Thanks for the response